# Time of jobs when they scheduled in task scheduler

Tags: database, scheduled-tasks, talend

I have many talend jobs, I am executing all those jobs in windows scheduler (task scheduler). I need to store the time of those jobs when they scheduled. how I can get the time of that? Please assist me on this.

Comment: If you want to check the runtime for your job you should turn on the logging and set a db with 3 tables where talend can store the log/stats/flows data. This can be used later.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Scheduler already stores a list of executed scheduled tasks where you can see the execution of tasks in either the last hour, day, week or 30 days.

If you're looking for something more programmatic and accessible from outside of Windows Scheduler then you could output something in the Talend job itself.

For example you could start your job with a quick entry to a log file or database table with the date-time of execution and the job name (retrievable from Talend's time handling functions and also system variables - try hitting ctrl+space to see a list of variables available to you) that is started and then finish the job with another log in the log file or database table with an entry for whether it succeeded or failed and the time that the job finished along with the job name.